# Write certificate chain to a PEM file

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, jsse

I am having a certificate chain where it may contain single certificate or certificate along with intermediate CA's certificate. Now I want to write this into a PEM format file. Is it possible to achieve with existing Java libraries without any third party libraries? Below is my code for certificate chain,

```
     final Collection<? extends Certificate> c =
         (Collection<? extends Certificate>) certFactory.generateCertificates(
             new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateString.getBytes()));
     final Certificate[] certs = (Certificate[]) c.toArray(new Certificate[] {});
```

How can I write this certs into a PEM file?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    out.println(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT);
    encoder.encodeBuffer(cert.getEncoded(), out);
    out.println(X509Factory.END_CERT);
```

or try this

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
x509cert.encode();
try {
    System.out.println("---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---");
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(x509cert.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("---END CERTIFICATE---");
} catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: or see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553642/write-pem-encoded-certificate-in-file-java

Comment: Is this cert is Certificate or Certificate[] ?